# How to eliminate specific rows from an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am working on a tool to analyse weather data. At this point all the data is loaded into a n×10-matrix called `master_array` containing the data as float64 datatype. I built some filters allowing the user to specify the years and months that should be used for further computing. These filters generate lists, e. g. a list containing integers like  `years=[2008, 2009, 2010]` for the years from 2008 to 2010 or another list `months=[8, 9, 10]` for August to October. 
The last column of `master_array` holds the years when the data was gathered, the column before the months and so on.

What I now struggle with is to build a function that is checking the last column of `master_array` for any matches with elements of the list `years` and delete all the **rows** from `master_array` which have no match.
If the list `years` is empty all available data should be kept in `master_array` for now.

The next step would do essentially the same but with the column before the last column in `master_array` and of course by using the list `months` instead of `years`.

I can not guarantee the values in the `master_array` are sorted but the function must filter the matrix never the less.

I am pretty sure I have to use numpys delete() and argwhere() but I am open for any simple and tidy solution that will help with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
To me it's *very* important to keep the `master_array` or at least a copy of it and delete the rows which are not needed anymore instead of creating a new array using vstack or something similar.

Comment: You may want to consider using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this kind of thing as it has plenty of functionality to select and slice time-indexed data (among other things). In any case, to continue with you approach, I think you should be able to make selection masks for your filters with [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

Comment: @jdehesa can you please give more detailed information about pandas, for example on which function(s) I should focus as I run out of time to finish this project?

Comment: Well if you have never used Pandas and you don't have much time, you may have to evaluate whether it is worth it now, but if you are going to be working with data in Python in the future, Pandas is almost indispensable. There are plenty of tutorials and resources around, for your case you can look for example at [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.11-working-with-time-series.html#Dates-and-times-in-pandas:-best-of-both-worlds).

Comment: For example if you had a data frame `df` with the index being the datetime you could do something like `df[(df.year >= 2008) & (df.year <= 2010) & (df.month >= 8) & (df.month <= 10)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your advice. I finally solved my problem without using a combination of numpy's delete() and argwhere(). At first I used pandas but then I realized it is not necessary.
To put it in a nutshell I am using the complement to the lists `months` and `years` (of course this requires to know what is the maximum time period of the dataset [see e.g. the list `all_years` in the example below], what is no problem as it is all included in my `master_array`) and with the complement I can achieve to exclude every row from `master_array` that is not matching the filters, finally exactly what I was looking for!

To give you an example of the final code:

```
for i in [x for x in all_years if x not in years]: #list containing the complement to the years chosen by user as filter
    master_arrayFilter = master_arrayFilter[master_arrayFilter[:,9] != i]
```

Note that I created a "copy" of `master_array` named `master_arrayFilter` in a previous line.

Still amazing that those two lines do the job! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask with `np.isin`, then replace the array with the masked one. **This is the recommended method from numpy**:

> Often it is preferable to use a boolean mask. For example:
>
> mask = np.ones(len(arr), dtype=bool) mask[[0,2,4]] = False result =
>   arr[mask,...]
>
> Is equivalent to `np.delete(arr, [0,2,4], axis=0)`, but allows further
>   use of `mask`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

#step 1: create an array with values and years (for illustration)
values = np.random.random(10)
years = np.array([2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2001,
                  2004, 2005, 2001, 2009, 2008])
master = np.vstack((values, years)).T
print(master[:,1])   # this will print master second column, i.e. years
>> ([2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2004, 2005, 2001, 2009, 2008])

# step 2: specify what years I want, then filter using a mask
filt_years = [2001, 2002]
mask = np.isin(master[:,1], filt_years)
print(mask)   #False values will be deleted
>> [ True  True  True False  True False False  True False False]

#step 3: apply mask and replace master (easier than deleting)
master = master[mask]
# or if you want to use delete:
master = np.delete(master, np.arange(len(master))[~mask], axis=0)
```

An example combining years and months and using `logical_and` (i.e. both months and years must be in the selected sets):

```
months = np.array([1,1,2,2,1,4,5,8,9,5])
master = np.vstack((values, months, years)).T
filt_years = [2001, 2002]
filt_months = [1,2]
mask = np.logical_and(np.isin(master[:,2], filt_years), np.isin(master[:,1], filt_months))
master = master[mask]
```

Comment: To be honest your answer containing many aspects I am not familiar with or simply don't understand.
To start with: What does the '.T' at the end of an array?
Did you understand, that my matrix is already containing years and months, most of theses values multiple times? 
In addition to that I am looking for a way to delete unnecessary rows from an existing array rather than to create a new one.

Comment: I added the explanation and extended the code to make it more "step by step". To answer your questions: 1) `.T` means transpose: when I use `vstack` I'm creating an array with a row of years, a row of values, and so on. with `.T` the rows become columns, so `master[:,1]`(first example) are the years... Note that I created the data only to illustrate the example 2) using `array = array[mask]` is easier than using `np.delete` and in fact recommended (see edit). You are not creating a new array, you are replacing the old one with a part of it.